# Can't update label inside keyPressed()

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I just started to learn Java. I have already looked Swing and at the moment I'm trying to do something with SWT.

But I have the next problem. Key Listener that I added for Text field is working, but inside this listener I can't change for example my label.

I have seen a few demos they worked, but I don't see any differences.

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class FirstClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();

        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setText("First Application");

        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(2, false);
        shell.setLayout(layout);

        Text word = new Text(shell,SWT.SINGLE | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FILL);
        GridData wordGrDt = new GridData();
        wordGrDt.heightHint = 130;
        wordGrDt.minimumHeight = 130;
        wordGrDt.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        wordGrDt.verticalAlignment = SWT.FILL;
        wordGrDt.horizontalSpan = 2;
        word.setLayoutData(wordGrDt);

        GridData statusGrDt = new GridData();
        statusGrDt.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        statusGrDt.horizontalSpan = 1;
        statusGrDt.horizontalAlignment = SWT.LEFT_TO_RIGHT;
        Label status = new Label(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        status.setEnabled(true);
        status.setText("");
        status.setLayoutData(statusGrDt);

        GridData checkGrDt = new GridData();
        checkGrDt.widthHint = 150;
        checkGrDt.horizontalSpan = 1;
        checkGrDt.horizontalAlignment = SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT;
        Button check = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        check.setText("Check");
        check.setLayoutData(checkGrDt);

        word.addKeyListener(new org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
                    System.out.println("worked!!!");
                    status.setText("ababahalamaha");
                }
            }
        });

        shell.setMinimumSize(400, 300);
        shell.open();
        shell.pack();

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `layout()` call to the parent of the `Label`:

```
word.addKeyListener(new org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyPressed(org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.keyCode == SWT.CR) {
            System.out.println("worked!!!");
            status.setText("ababahalamaha");
            status.getParent().layout();
        }
    }
});
```

The label originally has a width of `0`, as it doesn't contain any text. When you add content, the parent has to know to re-layout its children.

---

As a note:

Please check which style you use with which widget. A `Label` does not know what to do with the style `SWT.PUSH` for example.